# Quels sont les noms numéraux après 10 ?

Tags: vocabulaire

[Wikipédia écrit :](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nom_num%C3%A9ral)

> Les noms numéraux multiplicatifs sont identiques à l'adjectif
> correspondant : double (2x), triple (3x), quadruple (4x), quintuple
> (5x), sextuple (6x), septuple (7x), octuple (8x), nonuple (9x),
> décuple (10x), centuple (100x).

Quels sont les noms numéraux, pour onze (11x), douze, treize, etc. ? Pourquoi sauter de 10 à 100 et pas 1000 par exemple ?

Answer (score 5):

Beaucoup de numéraux sont inusités et inconnus faute de répondre à un besoin significatif, mais certains comme [Louis Meigret](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Meigret) ou d'autres se sont attelés à la tâche.

x11 à x19 : undecuple, [duodecuple](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/duod%C3%A9cuple), trédecuple / tridécuple, quatuorcuple / tetradécuple, quinquedecuple / pentadécuple, sexdecuple / hexadécuple, septendecuple / heptadécuple, octodecuple / octadécuple, novemdecuple / nonadécuple
x20 à x90 : [vingtuple](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vingtuple) / vintuple / icosuple, trentuple, quarantuple, cinquantuple, soixantuple, septantuple, huitantuple / huictantuple, [nonantuple](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonantuple)

Source des numéraux sans hyperlien, [Gérard Villemin](http://villemin.gerard.free.fr/Wwwgvmm/Numerati/Prefixes.htm), qui ajoute : *on préfèrera reformuler la phrase et dire douze fois, onze fois, treize fois, vingt fois, cinq cents fois, etc...*